# Selenium in Test or Production Phase

Tags: selenium

I have considered to use Selenium to test the critical functionality, that is written in a test case, and we are two developer only, no test team or QA user.

We are using different computer hardware with different version of windows but we use the same browser and VS tool version.

Before the production phase we need to use the Selenium to test the critical function, should everything be done in a test or development phase?

Can only one person who can use Selenium suite at a time (due to settings etc).

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean "can only one user develop selenium" or "can only one person run the suite at a time?"

Comment: That is my question. "can only one person run the suite at a time?"

Comment: Note that title says "Test or Production Phase" but details say "test or development phase"

Comment: I think the answer depends on more details.  Are you doing Agile?   Do you have good specifications?  Generally you want to test as early as possible - when code changes are still cheap and easy.

Comment: As for more than 1 person running tests, that is really a separate question.  The answer is that you should determine a code sharing strategy.  You can use a full-fledged tool like git or, if just two of you and you communicate well, you can just share files in some way - use a network drive, a google drive, manually send files to each other, etc.

Comment: We already havea code sharing strategy. We don't know how to use it in relation to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are familiar with selenium you can develop record/playback as quick test options for dev team
- It would be great if you can share your tests with dev for them to independently execute / reuse tests you developed
- From QA perspective you can develop data driven / reusable / framework level code. This will ensure you contribute for your framework in long run
- Earlier the bug detected lower the cost of fixing it. Since its a single member team you can offload / engage dev at earlier phase to identify / test at early stages
- Once your dev team is able to use raw selenium (recorded - tests) you can focus on QA tasks

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have a question.
If I understand about what you are telling me that if you have created the record/playback in my client computer that use windows 10 and I provide it to another  developer who use win 7, it should be working perfectly?

Comment: Yes throw-away solution for dev and a reusuable framework code for QA

Answer (score 1):

The critical test / smoke test should runs on development and all other environments, as all tests should be repeatable with automation, and efforts have been spent on writing the tests.

Assume you use Selenium for Web application testing, when multiple users run the same suite on the same environment, same time, test depends on data could fail if other test is updating the data. So you should avoid running the same suite on the environment and time. Using continuous integration tools such as [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins-ci.org/) can queue tests jobs to prevent that from happening. It is easy to configure with [selenium plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you elaborate more about "same suit"?

Comment: Same test suite. A collection of test cases that the team members are going to perform. In your case it would be test suite of smoke test. The test cases can be reuse in other test suite.

Comment: "Using continuous integration tools such as Jenkins can queue tests jobs to prevent that from happening. It is easy to configure with selenium plugin"
---------------

I went to the Jenkins website, that you have provided a link, I don't understand about how it can be used in relation a client computer in order to implement a smoke test? I dont have enough with info about applying settings for Jenkins with client computer.

Comment: Jenkins may be overkill if there are just 2 of you and you don't already know it.  I've also moved to circleCI and it feels more modern and may be easier to set up for newbies.